# How can I change the time that an e-mail was received via Microsoft Exchange Server or Microsoft Outlook?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, powershell, exchange

As the question says, how can I change the time that an e-mail was received either via Microsoft Outlook or via Microsoft Exchange Server (as an Administrator account) directly?

There are numerous GUI tools online that plug in to Microsoft Outlook and allow you to change various things (including the received date/time) of an e-mail, and these changes are then pushed back to the server.

My question though concerns how to do such without these shareware GUI tools that are available online i.e. directly through Microsoft Outlook or Microsoft Exchange Server (as an Administrator account) using PowerShell or the like.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: sounds like you are covering your tracks...

Answer (score -1):

You can make your inbox view (or any other view) *editable* under View/View Settings, 'Other Settings'. You will get a pop-out where the option 'Allow in-cell editing' is available:

[image]

Once you save this, many columns can be edited freely. Note that depending on which version of Outlook you have, the 'Received' column is explicitly blocked from being changed this way. I think this is intentional, so there probably is no  built-in way to enable it.